# ax.get_position wont give me position of all plots on multiple subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to overlap a matrix of subplots.

The code I am using is:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols =2, nrows = 2, figsize=(8,8), sharey=True,  facecolor = "#FFFFFF", subplot_kw=dict(polar=True) ,constrained_layout=True)
fig.tight_layout(h_pad=-5)

directions = [1,-1]
for ax,direction in zip(axes.ravel(), directions):
    shift_axes = 0.2 if direction == 1 else -0.2
    box = ax.get_position()
    print(box)
  
    box.x0 = box.x0 + shift_axes #x0 first coordinate of the box
    box.x1 = box.x1 + shift_axes #x1 last coordinate of the box

    ax.set_position(box)
```

Which returns:

[image]

If I print the results of box, I get only the first two. What am I doing wrong?
[image]

Comment: try `directions = [1, -1, 1, -1]` and think what `zip` does when its arguments are not the same length!

Comment: btw, you'd better use a `shifts = [+0.2, -0.2, +0.2, -0.2]` then `for ax, shift in zip(axes.flat, shifts): ...`

Comment: OMG! how could I miss that... thanks!

Comment: Someone wrote a song about that feeling _"And there's another memory that gets stuck \\ 
Inside the walls of my skull, waiting for its turn to talk \\ 
And it may be a few years \\ 
But you can bet it's there, waiting still \\ 
For me to be left alone in a room full of things that I've done"_, btw it's one of my favorite songs, for one reason or another :-)

Comment: ...a whole cake... ;)